# Updating value picked from DDL in DetailView

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, drop-down-menu, updating, detailview

(I found the way it's supposed to be done as shown in my **Answer** below.
I'm editing my question and deleting the code I initially put here, which was a mess, leaving just the definitions).

Win7, ASP4.5, empty_web_app in VS2013 with C#.  Recreated in a very simple project accessing two tables:

1st table "***Students***"

- ***student_ID***
- ***student_name***
- ***student_course_ID***  (is Forign Key)

2nd table "***Courses***"

- ***course_ID***
- ***course_name***

In my web page I have **DetailView1** showing details of student who's ***student_ID*** is taken from **txbStudent_ID**.
DetailView1 has Edit Delete and New.
When in UPDATE or INSERT mode I need to show the course_name (rather then the course ID) in a drop-down-list and update/insert accordingly.

No code behind.

My answer below is applicable to GRIDVIEW as well.

Gadi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was so wrong they way I coded my aspx.
So here is the right way to do it, for future beginners like I am now...
(with the help of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178294(v=vs.140).aspx)

```
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Student_ID"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txbStudent_ID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="student_ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="50px" Width="125px">
        <Fields>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="student_ID" HeaderText="student_ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="student_ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="student_name" HeaderText="student_name" SortExpression="student_name" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="student_course_ID" SortExpression="student_course_ID">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList 
                        ID="DropDownList1" 
                        runat="server" 
                        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" 
                        DataTextField="course_name" 
                        DataValueField="course_ID" 
                        SelectedValue='<%# Bind("student_course_ID") %>'>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList 
                        ID="DropDownList2" 
                        runat="server" 
                        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" 
                        DataTextField="course_name" 
                        DataValueField="course_ID" 
                        SelectedValue='<%# Bind("student_course_ID") %>'>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label 
                        ID="Label1" 
                        runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Bind("student_course_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ShowInsertButton="True" ShowDeleteButton="True" />
        </Fields>
    </asp:DetailsView>

    <asp:SqlDataSource 
        ID="SqlDataSource1" 
        runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Course_Student_Connection %>" 
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Students] ([student_name], [student_course_ID]) VALUES (@student_name, @student_course_ID)" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Students] WHERE ([student_ID] = @student_ID)"
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Students] SET [student_name] = @student_name, [student_course_ID] = @student_course_ID WHERE [student_ID] = @student_ID" 
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Students] WHERE [student_ID] = @student_ID">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="student_ID" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="student_name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="student_course_ID" Type="Int32" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txbStudent_ID" Name="student_ID" PropertyName="Text" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="student_name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="student_course_ID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="student_ID" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:SqlDataSource 
        ID="SqlDataSource2" 
        runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Course_Student_Connection %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [course_ID], [course_name] FROM [Courses]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I do hope it will save some time for others.
Stackoverflow is THE greatest and by far the best Q&A site on the web!!!
Gadi.